# ASP.NET C# How to hide and display particular field inside Repeater? (if statement)

Tags: c#, asp.net

Needed some help here,
So I am using repeater and retrieve some data from DB then put into the repeater, the thing is that for certain data value I would like to display it differently in the HTML, basically do IF checking inside Repeater to determine which HTML code to use, can someone help me with that?

I have two different codes

```
<div class="message-data">
  <span class="message-data-name"><i class="fa fa-circle you"></i> You</span>
</div>
<div class="message you-message">
A new client?!?! I would love to help them, but where are we going to find the time?
```

and

```
 <li class="clearfix">
    <div class="message-data align-right">
      <span class="message-data-name">Ada, your OperationsAlly</span> <i class="fa fa-circle me"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="message me-message float-right"> We should take a look at your onboarding and service delivery workflows, for most businesess there are many ways to save time and not compromise quality.  </div>
  </li>
```

As you can see, how do I put IF statement, for the first one like if (username == "You") and second one if (Username != "You"). Assume that the DB I retrieve has attribute named "Username"

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It honestly is going to depend on how you retrieve your data.

You can always create a function and pass the value form your database to the function and have the function return the correct html.

```
<%#GetHtmlForUserName(Eval("Username"))%>
```

The in your function, perhaps in your code behind:

```
protected string GetHtmlForUserName(string userName)
    {
        if (userName == "You")
        {
            return "<div class='message-data'>\n" +
                    "  <span class='message-data-name'><i class='fa fa-circle you'></i> You</span>\n" +
                    "</div>\n" +
                    "<div class='message you-message'>\n" +
                    "A new client?!?! I would love to help them, but where are we going to find the time?";
        }
        else
        {
            return "<li class='clearfix'>\n" +
                    "    <div class='message-data align-right'>\n" +
                    "      <span class='message-data-name'>Ada, your OperationsAlly</span> <i class='fa fa-circle me'></i>\n" +
                    "    </div>\n" +
                    "    <div class='message me-message float-right'> We should take a look at your onboarding and service delivery workflows, for most businesess there are many ways to save time and not compromise quality.  </div>\n" +
                    "  </li>\n";

        }
    }
```

The best approach is to load a custom control that displays the text based on the user name but that is a more advanced topic.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. However, how to put that into the Repeater as for the getHTML and what kind of code should I put in the code behind? I cant just copy paste the html right? Sorry, I am new ><

Comment: Put that exact code in the html.  For the html in the function, I'll update my answer.

Comment: So you can call a function in a data bound item the same way you would bind the data item. `<%# Eval("Description") %>` in fact is a call to a function called eval.

Comment: Thanks for your help, so in the html code side I put Label like this                 <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# GetHtmlForUserName(Eval ("Username"))%>'></asp:Label>, that is fine right? Thanks

Comment: Thank you so very much. It works perfectly, one last question. How do I add slider into the template? So put all the chat into a box and provide slider so the entire page won't be filled with messages

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can put them in

like

```
<asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server">
<div class="message-data">
    <span class="message-data-name"><i class="fa fa-circle you"></i>You</span>
</div>
<div class="message you-message">
    A new client?!?! I would love to help them, but where are we going to find the time?
</div>
</asp:Panel>

<asp:Panel ID="Panel2" runat="server">
<li class="clearfix">
    <div class="message-data align-right">
        <span class="message-data-name">Ada, your OperationsAlly</span> <i class="fa fa-circle me"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="message me-message float-right">We should take a look at your onboarding and service delivery workflows, for most businesess there are many ways to save time and not compromise quality.  </div>
</li>
</asp:Panel>
```

then

you can use IF statement in code behind (C#)

```
if (username == "You") {
    Panel1.Visible = true; 
}
```

Comment: This approach could work but only if there will be one item in the repeater. If the repeater is going to have multiple items you have a problem.

Comment: The best approach is to load a custom user control that displays the text based on the user name but that is a more advanced topic.

Answer (score -1):

If you're using ASP.net MVC Identity you can simply use this below:

```
@if(!Request.IsAuthenticated)
{
   <div class="message-data">
    <span class="message-data-name"><i class="fa fa-circle you"></i>You</span>
   </div>
    <div class="message you-message">A new client?!?! I would love to help them, but where are we going to find the time? </div>
}
else
{ 
      <div class="message-data align-right">
        <span class="message-data-name">@Html.Raw(User.Identity.GetUserName()), your OperationsAlly</span>      <i class="fa fa-circle me"></i>
       </div>
      <div class="message me-message float-right"> We should take a look at your onboarding and service delivery workflows, for most businesess there are many ways to save time and not compromise quality.  </div> 
}
```

Comment: Don't think he's using MVC, hence the repeater control. He also wants the name of the user out of the database, which in MVC he would pull from his model  not User.Identity